Newly created epic and user story in ADO cannot sync to Service now
When creating new Epics and User Stories in Azure DevOps (ADO), these items are not being synchronized to ServiceNow (SN). I have created a new Epic in ADO and a new User Story ,but they are not reflected in ServiceNow. What could be causing this synchronization failure?
I Reviewed Integration Configuration, Verified Permissions, Tested Connectivity but everything is configured properly. But unable to resolve this!


Did it work before? 2. If you make some changes to the existing work item, will it be synced to ServiceNow? 3. You can try to create a new connection follow the steps here and check if it works.

